# How to make a schedule table query from SQL Server 2012?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I need help to make a schedule table for employee from my table the main problem is the row not start from first row on every column so the row keep continue, see picture below:

[image: Table]

we can see that the next column is null on the first row and continue from the last row. this is my query and table relations, you can see it below.

[image]

```
SELECT        (SELECT        PEGAWAI.NAMAPEGAWAI
                      WHERE        (JADWAL.HARIKERJA = 'Tuesday')) AS Selasa,
                         (SELECT        PEGAWAI.NAMAPEGAWAI
                           WHERE        (JADWAL.HARIKERJA = 'Wednesday')) AS Rabu,
                         (SELECT        PEGAWAI.NAMAPEGAWAI
                           WHERE        (JADWAL.HARIKERJA = 'Thursday')) AS Kamis,
                         (SELECT        PEGAWAI.NAMAPEGAWAI
                           WHERE        (JADWAL.HARIKERJA = 'Friday')) AS Jumat,
                         (SELECT        PEGAWAI.NAMAPEGAWAI
                           WHERE        (JADWAL.HARIKERJA = 'Sabtu')) AS Saturday,
                         (SELECT        PEGAWAI.NAMAPEGAWAI
                           WHERE        (JADWAL.HARIKERJA = 'Monday')) AS Minggu FROM            JADWAL INNER JOIN
                     JADWALPEGAWAI ON JADWAL.IDJADWAL = JADWALPEGAWAI.IDJADWAL INNER JOIN
                     PEGAWAI ON JADWALPEGAWAI.IDPEGAWAI = PEGAWAI.IDPEGAWAI WHERE        (JADWAL.SHIFT = 'I')
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It would really help people who want to answer your question if you put the query as text in the question, not a picture. Likewise the tables.

Comment: already put the query as text. Thanks

Comment: What kind of schedule you are trying to build for your employees as part of query output? Is it that you want to know - who all employees have got their shifts on any specific day of a week? Are you trying to create a weekly roster for your employees as query output?  If I understand correctly `PEGAWAI` contains list of all the employees. `JADWALPEGAWAI` is a relationship table. What does `JADWAL` table contains?

Comment: Its has been solved dude. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be causing your query not to behave as you expect, is that you have no `GROUP BY` clause in your query, which means that you get one row of output for each for (in this case) each row of the `JadwalPegawai` table.

At a minimum, adding `GROUP BY Pegawai.NamaPegawai` after your `WHERE …` clause should fix this, but I think that we can do even better:

```
Select Min(iif(j.Harikerja = 'Tuesday', p.NamaPegawai, Null)) As Selasa,
    Min(iif(j.Harikerja = 'Wednesday', p.NamaPegawai, Null)) As Rabu,
    …
  From Jadwal As j
  Join JadwalPegawai As jp On j.IdJadwal = jp.IdJadwal
  Join Pegawai As p On jp.IdPegawai = p.IdPegawai
  Where j.Shift = 'I'
  Group By p.NamaPegawai;
```

This should be logically equivalent, but doesn't use subqueries. Hope I didn't make any spelling errors, I'm not too good at bahasa Indonesia...

Comment: Thanks a lot i add a "order by p.NamaPegawai;" and now its worked as i want.

Comment: i mean "order by p.NamaPegawai desc;" Thanks.